# Auto update CSS from SASS/SCSS in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

Maybe I'm confused on how SASS/SCSS works within Rails (2.3.8.) but I was under the impression that if I included the option

```
Sass::Plugin.options[:always_update] = true
```

that whenever I changed my SCSS file and then hit the page (controller) again, the SCSS would recompile.

I can't seem to get this to work, and can't seem to find a good tutorial / example for it.  I've tried setting the above property in the Environment.rb file, but it didn't seem to do anything.  I tried putting it in its own initializer with require 'sass' but that doesn't seem to work either.

What am I missing?  Or am i just forced to keep a terminal open with a sass --watch command running to be able to rapidly debug / change my styles?

thx

Answer (score 2):

I'm using rails 3.1, but had the same issue. In the [sass-rails](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails) gem, the docs say

```
:always_update - This option is not supported. Sprockets uses a controller to access stylesheets in development mode instead of a full scan for changed files.
```

which could explain why your `:always_update` option wasn't working.

For my problem, it was pretty much because I had `config.action_controller.perform_caching` in development.rb set to true (to fix some other bug in an old gem). So to fix it I changed it to:

```
# config/environments/development.rb
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run `compass init` in your rails project. It will set up the following:

- config/compass.rb
- config/initializers/compass.rb

Comment: I ended up going a completely different direction in the end.  (using Less instead of SASS, per a friend of mine's suggestion)  However, if someone else knows the above is true or has tested it out, post a comment and I'll mark this one as the Answer for posterity and google searches. :)

Thanks Andrew!

Comment: Less is called less for a reason. SASS/Compass for the win. See https://gist.github.com/674726 for Chris Eppstein's comparison (he is the author of Compass).

Answer (score 0):

You should reload a normal View of a Controller instead of just the stylesheet directly.

btw, as the documentation says `:always_update` updates the css files on every controller reload:

> Whether the CSS files should be
>   updated every time a controller is
>   accessed, as opposed to only when the
>   template has been modified. Defaults
>   to false. Only has meaning within
>   Rack, Ruby on Rails, or Merb.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem, that I name my files ends with .css.scss. After just using .scss it works.